# How to add JProgressBar in java Eclipse on WindowBuilder JFrame

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I'm a new java eclipse window builder user and are I'm try to make work a progress bar but don know were to start
[image]
[image]

Comment: Avoid "window builders" on general, they won't help you in the long run and tend to create unmanageable code and encourage bad habits (even in experienced developers). Avoid `null` layouts, "pixel perfect layouts" are an illusion. Instead, take the time to learn how to use the layout management APIs, see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details. You should also be familiar with [How to Use Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)

Comment: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551